# How to use when loading the page showing pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, onload

My concept is when service location is not matched while show the popup menu onloading of

```js
function buydisable() {
  alert("HOO");
  return false; //not showed the alert 
  $.post(jssitebaseUrl + "/ajaxAction.php", {
    'action': 'buydisable'
  }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
    return false;
    $("#commonDivForAjax").modal('show').html(data);
    $('.ui-loader').hide();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onload="buydisable()" disabled="disabled">{$LANG.conVwJbDtl_buyNow}</a>
```

the page

Comment: Can you please re-phrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your `onload` should be on the `body` tag.

```
<body onload="buydisable()">

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="disabled">{$LANG.conVwJbDtl_buyNow}</a> 

</body>
```

Comment: Not ideally the event will not fire on a tag

Answer (score 0):

`onload` does not fire on `a` tag; this event it only supports with few tags like listed below.

```
<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>
```

For more details can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).

So resolution either use on load event on the `body` or create a blank `image tag`.